# Having a banner update on a daily basis

Tags: php, flash, banner

I'm currently putting together some basic animated HTML5 banners for a client, and they've asked for one based around their uptime (they're a SAAS provider). This banner will update the days of uptime unless an incident occurs. I've designed the banner in Adobe Animate, and have all the numbers available up to 1,000, but am struggling to think how I implement this. I guess the banner needs to call a script or similar?

Any thoughts/feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is the following

- Store the current date/time into a cache with an expiry of 0 (never expires) ([A tutorial](http://www.script-tutorials.com/how-to-use-memcache-with-php/) if you have access to memcached).
- Have a method for the client to reset uptime. This would essentially be setting the cached value to the current time.
- Determine which banner to get based on `max((current datetime - cached datetime), 0)`